# How to make a table in HTML with variable and fixed column widths and grouping header?

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I style a table in html so it gets laid out like this:

```
<-       full page width             ->
<-20px->< dynamic ><-20px->< dynamic  >
+------------------+-------------------+
¦ A                ¦ B                 ¦ header row 1
+-------+----------+-------+-----------+
+ A1    ¦ A2       ¦ B1    ¦ B2        ¦ header row 2
+-------+----------+-------+-----------+
¦ a1      a2         b1      b2        ¦ data rows
```

Without the grouping header row, I would do it like this:

```
<table style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed;">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:20px;">A1</th>
    <th style="           ">A2</th>
    <th style="width:20px;">B1</th>
    <th style="           ">B2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This works nicely, when I resize the browser window, the two cols without explicit width take the available space, while the two fixed cols stay at the given width.

But when I add the grouping header row, I have not found any way to assign widths so that the table has two fixed and two adaptable columns.

Comment: As a workaround, you could just add another element (e.g. a DIV containing two DIVs) above the table to contain the first headers, otherwise you lose the styling on the header row 2.

Comment: and how would I make sure the divs adapt to the table column widths?

Comment: Aren't the top two headers always 50%?

Comment: in this simplified example, yes, but not in my actual case

Comment: This is a great question. I had the same problem, and had a hard time figuring out how to ask a question like this. You nailed it. And your solution is perfect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your contributions and some search in W3C docs, I came to this solution:

```
<table border="1" style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%;">
  <col style="width:20px;">
  <col style="width:50%;">
  <col style="width:20px;>
  <col style="width:50%;>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">A</th>
    <th colspan="2">B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>A1</th>
    <th>A2</th>
    <th>B1</th>
    <th>B2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2 very long text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The table-layout:fixed is required to have the column widths as specified. Else the widths are calculated from cell contents, which is OK in the example but a trouble in reality.

In fixed layout, in absence of col elements, the first row is used to define the column widths. That's why cell widths worked with a single header row, but not with the grouping header. Providing col elements solves it.

Comment: Thank You! This is the only answer that actually works for all of the specifications in the question. It is the perfect answer. I do not get why this is not more upvoted, but I am thankful that it was the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

I can only test it on one browser here, but removing the table-layout fixs it here.

```
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">A</th>
    <th colspan="2">B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 20px;">A1</th>
    <th>A2</th>
    <th style="width: 20px;">B1</th>
    <th>B2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20px;">a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td style="width: 20px;">b1</td>
    <td >b2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Some browser do seem to have problems: [Internet Explorer 8 table cell width bug with colspan set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412692/internet-explorer-8-table-cell-width-bug-with-colspan-set)

Comment: I tried it without the `style`s on the <td> and it works okay too. at least on FF

Comment: it works for the example. However, without table-layout:fixed, the two stretching columns get widths proportionally distributed to their cell content widths, replace b2 by a long text and you see what I mean

Comment: @Markus Seems like you can't have a fixed layout and then asking to change the width. You could set the first row (with colspan 2) to each column be 50%.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `<colgroup />` and setting the widths via CSS (don't use inline styles if at all possible). As you saw, you need to set the width for each column when you have `colspan` involved, but that's really not an issue for HTML/CSS.

**CSS**

```
table{
    width:100%;

.narrow{
    width:40px;
}
.dynamic{
    width:auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>

<colgroup class="narrow"/>
<colgroup class="dynamic"/>
<colgroup class="narrow"/>
<colgroup class="dynamic"/>

<tr>
    <th colspan="2">A</th>
    <th colspan="2">B</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>A1</th>
    <th>A2</th>
    <th>B1</th>
    <th>B2</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
</tr>
[ ... ]

</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/X7TgN/1/

Comment: Yes, I agree about using css instead of inline. I'm a little irritated by the fact that html 5 doesn't support most of the colgroup and col attributes (at least they say so in w3 schools)?

Comment: [Several of the possible attributes on colgroup & col are depreciated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup), but those same attributes are depreciated basically everywhere (`align` for example should be replaced with CSS). [The colgroup & col elements themselves are part of the HTML5 specs.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-colgroup-element)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed;">
  <tr>
   <th colspan="2">A1</th>
   <th colspan="2">A2</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <th colspan="1">A1</th>
   <th colspan="1">A2</th>
   <th colspan="1">B1</th>
   <th colspan="1">B2</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="1">a1</td>
   <td colspan="1">a2</td>
   <td colspan="1">b1</td>
   <td colspan="1">b2</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Using colspan will solve your problem. Try the one above and let me know what you get.

Comment: I think no need to write `colspan=1` explicitly.

Comment: @david : yea it is not needed, but i put it so that he ll know how colspan works.

Comment: my problem is about setting column widths, so that two cols stay fixed and two adapt to containing element width